# SQL : select rows from table 1 and exists (rows from table 2)

Tags: php, mysql, select, exists

I am trying to select rows and add to this selection a boolean to test the existence of a many-to-many relationship recorded in an other table.

Here is my code :

```
$q = $this->dao->prepare('
        SELECT wishlists.id, wishlists.title, wishlists.comment, wishlists.date, users.name, users.username
        FROM wishlists
            LEFT JOIN users ON wishlists.user = users.id
            WHERE users.username = :username
        ORDER BY wishlists.date DESC
        ');

    $q->bindValue(':username', $user);

    $q->execute();
```

This will return a table with all my fields. I would like to add a column to this table with this kind of subquery :

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM wishlists_following WHERE wishlist_id = wishlists.id AND user_id = :current_user_id)
```

Where current_user_id is the id of the visitor and $user is the current user profile page.

What is the best way to do that?

The goal is to get all informations about a wishlist AND to know if current user is following this wishlist (in order to display a following button or not for each wishlist returned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you use a LEFT JOIN between wishlist and users, if there is no related user to a wishlist, you will get a NULL value for columns username and user.

So I don't think you need another query : you just have to test the nulliness of column users.name once you get the results of your first query.

Comment: Sorry, I have made a mistake in my subquery. Actually, the user_id must be equal to the current visitor id, not the user profile id. (wish username is contained in $user)

Comment: It does not change the answer : with your first query, you will be able to retrieve all wishlists, including the ones that are not associated with the user_id you passed as parameter.

Is visitor another table in your DB model, or an id of user table ?

Please give information.

Comment: It is the same table. Here is my DB : 

users (id, username, and other informations)
wishlists (id, title, comment, user_id) -> Many-to-one relationship
whishlists_following (id, user_id, wishlist_id) -> Many-to-many relationship

So user 1 (visitor) can follow a wishlist owned by user 2 (current profile page).

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are trying to do.
I would do as following :

SELECT w.title, w.comment, wf.user_id FROM WISHLIST w
LEFT JOIN WISHLIST_FOLLOWING wf ON w.user_id = wf.user_id


wf.user_id = the visitor id (I assumed you already knew it).

You should retrieve something as followed :

w.title    w.comment    wf.user_id
WL1        Comment1     1
WL2        Comment2     3
WL3        Comment3     NULL

Means WL3 is not followed by the visitor.

Comment: Ok, Thx. While you were answering I found that solution too.

I now ask myself if it is the best way to do that (about performance). I ask the question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678262/mysql-select-rows-from-table-1-and-test-if-rows-exists-in-table-2?noredirect=1#comment32770310_21678262

Answer (score 0):

Check the name or username fields in your first query - either in query directly or in your script after executing the query, if it is null it means user is not following the wishlist, otherwise s/he does.
Key thing is using LEFT join allowing this and you already have it.