# Mysql : select rows from table 1 and test if rows exists in table 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my query :

```
$q = $this->dao->prepare('
        SELECT wishlists.id, wishlists.title, wishlists.comment, 
               wishlists.date, users.name, users.username, 
               wishlist_following.id as wid
        FROM wishlists
            LEFT JOIN users ON wishlists.user = users.id
            LEFT JOIN wishlist_following ON wishlist_following.user_id = 25 
                AND wishlist_following.wishlist_id = wishlists.id
            WHERE users.username = :username
        ORDER BY wishlists.date DESC
        ');
```

Where "25" is the ID of the visitor. I have a "wid" key in my table which is null if the current user (id : 25) is not following the returned wishlist.

Here is my DB and goal :

Users (id, username, etc.)

Whislists (id, title, comment, user_id) -> many-to-one relationship with users table

wishlist_following (id, user_id, wishlist_id) -> many-to-many relationship with users table

My goal : I want to get the wishlists from user's profile (extracting username from URL) AND to know for each wishlist if the current user (the visitor) is following this list.

Is it the best way?

Comment: Note that "LEFT JOIN x ... WHERE x.something = 'y'" is the same as "INNER JOIN x ... WHERE x.something = 'y' "

Comment: yes. I knew that. Is there a performance difference between LEFT and INNER JOIN?

Comment: There can be a performance difference, because with the outer join you "create" records that you dismiss later. It is better to use an inner join. And using the appropriate join enhances readablity, too.

Comment: In practice, the two queries will be identical. An EXPLAIN EXTENDED (followed by SHOW WARNINGS) can prove this.

Comment: LEFT JOIN is by default an INNER JOIN, no? So, no matter with outer join?

Comment: @SébastienLeGall INNER JOIN is not LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query

```
SELECT w.title
FROM users u, wishlists w, wishlist_following wf
WHERE u.id = 1 -- visitor
AND w.user_id = 3 -- viewed profile
AND wf.user_id = u.id
AND wf.wishlist_id = w.id
```

should return wishlists, followed by visitor (id 1), from user profile with id=3

Okay, I figure it out, try this:

```
SELECT w.title, wf.id
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN wishlists w ON w.user_id = 3 -- viewed profile
LEFT JOIN wishlist_following wf ON wf.wishlist_id = w.id
WHERE u.id = 1 -- visitor
```

Simplified version:

```
SELECT w.title, wf.id
FROM users u, wishlists w
LEFT JOIN wishlist_following wf ON wf.wishlist_id = w.id
WHERE u.id = 1 -- visitor
AND w.user_id = 3 -- viewed profile
```

Comment: Thx, I did not know I could to that kind of select.

However, that is not what I am trying to do.

I wish to select all the wishlist owned by the viewed profile. And for each, show a "follow" button if the list is not followed by the visitor.

Comment: Find updated query. Now it return all wishlists from profile. You should check returned wf.id. If it is NULL - show 'follow' button.

Comment: Thx, but this is the same query as mine except that you're selecting users instead of wishlists. 

Why should this query be more efficient than mine?

Comment: Well, you query was okay. In fact, you must LEFT JOIN only that tables, witch may not contain rows (return NULLs). All other tables better to link with simple SELECT. Thus, I simplify my query and update post.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal correctly, something like that:

```
SELECT
a.*,
CASE WHEN b.ID IS NULL THEN ‘No’ ELSE ‘Yes’ END AS Following
FROM
wishlists a
LEFT JOIN wishlist_following b ON b.wishlist_id = a.id AND b.user_id = <ID_USER_VISITOR>
WHERE a.user_id = <ID_USER_OWNER>
```

Comment: Yes, this is it. Except that b.id would be b.wishlist_id.

In my query I did not use CASE but test it with php : empty(return ['b.id'])

Is it better to case it with mysql?

Comment: @SébastienLeGall If possible to use Mysql - you must use it. CASE WHEN is not heavy operation, so I think it better. But you can make some experiments with it and choose best solution.

Comment: @SébastienLeGall I changed b.id to b.wishlist_id